# Seting TextCodepage property of WorkbookSaveAsArgs (Workbook) object

Tags: csv, excel

Folks, I'm trying to set the `TextCodepage`property of `WorkbookSaveAsArgs` used as argument for an `Workbook` method SaveAs. Which is used to convert .xls files in .csv ones. However, this property receives a generic object and I don't know how to properly set it. In msdn documentation it only say [Ignored for all languages in Microsoft Excel.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841185.aspx) or [Not used in U.S. English Excel.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). When my documents are being convert, it generate invalid characters cause my input files are in portuguese. Thus, I need a encode mode that accept this language. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only suggest saving with FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, instead of xlCSV. But use a ".csv" file extension when you do so. This should preserve your portuguese characters.

Answer (score 0):

It works to me, use the "FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8". Try if it works, i suggest looking the documentation too "https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31280265)