# Excel 2007: save as UTF-8 encoded CSV

Tags: excel, utf-8, excel-2007, export-to-csv, vba

Excel 2007 has no standard UI controls to save UTF-8 encoded CSV file.

I am trying to write a macro:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "sms.csv", FileFormat:= xlCSV, TextCodepage:= ????
```

What should be in place of `????` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is something like a phantom - everyone is talking about it and no one know what is it. Anyway I think this link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034049/seting-textcodepage-property-of-workbooksaveasargs-workbook-object

Comment: Alordiel, I've seen that question. The solution doesn't fit my needs. I'll try to import Excel type library and then look it through.

Comment: I had a problem saving a csv created from excel in unicode. So i usually open the csv file with the notepad and then use the option to change the unicode from there. Not sure if this would be possible with VBA. Have read this topics but don't know if they will fit your case: [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/700698-how-read-unicode-write-out-text-file-macro.html)

Comment: It seems that it is better to loop through entire worksheet and insert commas with own macro, then save the string to an UTF-8 text file.