# Excel SaveAs changes the date format

Tags: c#, excel, date

I am trying to save an excel file as a csv but it changes the date from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy. Is there another parameter I can add to the save as instruction to achieve this?

`excelWorkbook.SaveAs(newFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);`

I tried to add Local:=true but that did not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. The cells are formatted as UK dates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034049/seting-textcodepage-property-of-workbooksaveasargs-workbook-object

Comment: excelWorkbook.SaveAs(newFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true); This seems to have sorted it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Meehow - I had the same problem where I was using the SaveAs function to convert an XLSX file to a CSV, but it also converting any cell values found as dates from UK format -> US format.

Changing the below worked perectly

OLD:
    `XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive`

NEW:
    `XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange`

Complete code:
    `xlWorkbook.SaveAs(toCSVFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this worked for me:

```
workbook.SaveAs(csvFileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVMSDOS, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
workbook.Close(false);
```

Note the use of Close with the argument "false" (do not save on close). Turns out saving on close was reverting to US date format.

Answer (score -2):

Store the date as "text" with a macro : there is no such thing as "formatting" in CSV, so dates are displayed the same way.