# VBA Export and save to CSV issues

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting

Found the below code online, though it's a bit strange when I run the macro for dates as my dates will convert from:
[DD/MM/YYYY] to [MM/DD/YYYY]

example:
31/07/2017 to 07/31/2017.

anyone able to assist, I would want to keep it was [DD/MM/YYYY].

Refer to below:

```
Dim strName As String
Dim filepath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv"

ActiveSheet.Copy    'copy the sheet as a new workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "File has been Created and Saved as:  " & vbCr & strName, , "Copy & Save Report"
```

thanks,

Comment: I think the original excel have set the format to [DD/MM/YYYY].  The CSV will not save the "format", and it will use the format of your PC's regional setting.

Comment: sorry, I would want to avoid it & keep it as [DD/MM/YYYY]

Comment: you could try to explicitly Format the column to your preffered dateformat

Comment: If receiving end allows, think about choosing YYYY-MM-DD date format. It is ISO standard, it is clearly readable around the world, and date 2017-03-05 is clear to understand, unlike 05/03/2017 (it is May or March). Abandon awkward local date formats, consider going international.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your local language settings (specified in Control Panel), the following should work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
```

This should ideally be used by specifying the `TextCodepage` parameter of the `SaveAs` method.
However, according to [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel), this parameter is ignored for all languages of Excel.

A previous [question on SO addresses this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034049/seting-textcodepage-property-of-workbooksaveasargs-workbook-object) and suggests instead using `FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText`, and then setting the extension to `.csv`, i.e.:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strName & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
```

However, this does not seem to work for my part when testing your scenario.